# PyQt Signals for ROS callbacks in RQT Plugin

Tags: ros, rospy, pyqt, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

while writing a RQT plugin I had a hard time to figure out, how to **connect a rospy callback to a PyQt SLOT** in order to update the UI in a correct way.

The [ROS WIKI](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin#Using_rospy) only tells you, that one should not directly modify Widgets in a callback, due to Thread-Safety but lacks an example...
So I propose to add a link to an example plugin in the Wiki which shows how to connect a ROS callback to a qt SLOT and update widgets (unfortunately I don't know one).

Can someone point out a good plugin code as an example?

Thanks,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224152/pyqt-signals-for-ros-callbacks-in-rqt-plugin/) by [Andreas Hermann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22601/andreas-hermann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2016-01-15

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I answer my own question, showing my solution how to pipe message data via Qt SIGNALS and SLOTS, which hopefully helps others.
So after initializing the plugin, I subscibe to a toppic with a custom message type, and in the message callback I just emit a SIGNAL carrying the whole message.
In the according SLOT I then update the UI Widgets with the message data.
I had to use the most basic `PyQt_PyObject` as data format to transfer my custom message type.

```
def __init__(self, context):
    foo()
    bar()
    and_so_on()

    self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('monitoring_result', MyMessageType, self.monitoringCallback,  queue_size=1)
    self.connect(self, SIGNAL("changeUI(PyQt_PyObject)"), self.monitoringSlot)

def monitoringCallback(self, data):
    self.emit(SIGNAL("changeUI(PyQt_PyObject)"), data)

def monitoringSlot(self, data):
    self._widget.lcdGoalID.display(data.current_trajectory + 1)
    self._widget.progressBar.setValue(data.max_num_collisions)
    self._widget.progressBar.setRange(0, data.coll_threshold)

    p = self._widget.palette()
    self._widget.setAutoFillBackground(True);
    if data.severe_collision:
        p.setColor(self._widget.backgroundRole(), Qt.red)
    else:
        p.setColor(self._widget.backgroundRole(), Qt.green)
    self._widget.setPalette(p)
```

---

Originally posted by [Andreas Hermann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22601/andreas-hermann/) with karma: 106 on 2016-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [quanghai](https://answers.ros.org/users/42012/quanghai/) on 2019-06-04**:
Thanks! but I get error: AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'emit'
Please help me!

**Comment by [Neo Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/74038/neo-nguyen/) on 2021-05-29**:
Yeah, after search in Gooogle, and I have found the topic can have our for this problem is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948455/pyqt5-how-to-connect-emit
and https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html (for more information to understand)
It.'s mean the first we find the signal, connect to function, and emit a signal to go to slot function. (yah, it mean that.)